# How to pass tick labels as slider value for Angular Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-slider

I am using the Angular Bootstrap slider (seiyria) with ticks and tick labels, when I click on the slider, getting ticks value, but I need tick labels value on-click of the slider. Is it possible?

Comment: post more details about what you're doing. This will help us to help you.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle.